# Easy way to check if nested list has any entries

Tags: python

If we have:

```
seq = []
```

To check if it is empty, we can do:

```
print "empty" if not seq else "not empty"
```

However, this will not work if we have the following:

```
seq[[],[]]
```

Is there a simple way to check this?

I understand that we can do:

```
for mini_seq in seq:
    print "empty" if not mini_seq else "not empty"
```

but is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT**:
For clarification, while my above method may not suggest it, I wanted one output as many responders figured out, anyway.

Comment: Is the nesting level fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
print 'empty' if not any(seq) else 'not empty'
```

Comment: Or `print 'not empty' if any(seq) else 'empty'`. Either way, that's beautifully Pythonic.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to determine whether every sublist is empty, use `not any(seq)`. To print a message separately for each sublist, your approach is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check if any one of the sublist has any values

```
flag = False
for i in seq:
    if i:
        flag = True

if flag:
    print "Not empty"
else:
    print "Not empty"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def deep_empty(l):
    """Returns True if l is an empty list, or if all its elements are deep_empty."""
    if not isinstance(l, list):
        return False
    return all(deep_empty(element) for element in l)
```

Recursively search the tree for anything that isn't a list. Note that this fails if there's a cycle:

```
l = []
l.append(l)
print deep_empty(l) # Oh no!
```

Comment: You generally should use `isinstance(l, list)` instead of `type(l) is not list`. The latter doesn't handle inheritance.

Comment: @Blender: Edited. Personally, I hate dealing with unexpected subclasses of built-ins like `list`. So many of them break invariants like "`+` is concatenation", "`x[i]` does not prolong the lifetime of i", or "if `i in d2`, then `d1[i] is d2[i]` after `d1.update(d2)`". Even if the thing says it's a list or an int or a dict or whatever, I don't feel safe calling it one.